# xsim multiple choice repeating letter that is designated as \correct

Tags: xsim

Why is the (C) popping up instead of (D). (D) should be the right solution. Code copy/pasted from xsim manual.

```
\NewTasksEnvironment[label=(\Alph*),label-width=15pt]{choices}[\choice]
\newcommand*\correct{\thetask\expanded{\SetExerciseProperty{choice}{\thetask}}}

\begin{exercise}
The system of units that is based on the powers of 10 is called 
    \begin{choices}(1)
        \choice US System of Units
        \choice EU System of Units
        \choice Imperial System
        \choice[\correct] The Metric System
    \end{choices}
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
    \GetExerciseProperty{choice}
\end{solution}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post your code to include all preamble and the `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` tags?

Comment: In any case, I can confirm that the example file `xsim-issue-49.tex` included in the `xsim` package also produce the incorrect output. I'll file a bug pointing it to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the definition of the `\correct` macro to

```
\newcommand*\correct{\refstepcounter{task}\thetask\expanded{\SetExerciseProperty{choice}{\thetask}}}
```

(Possibly the `tasks` package changed its behavior; it would make sense that when a user uses a custom label the counter for the original label should not be incremented.)

---

On the other hand, I am not sure why it is necessary to put the "`\correct`" inside brackets. To me it makes more sense to do

```
\NewTasksEnvironment[label=(\Alph*),label-width=15pt]{choices}[\choice]
\newcommand*\correct{\expanded{\SetExerciseProperty{choice}{\thetask}}}

\begin{exercise}
The system of units that is based on the powers of 10 is called 
    \begin{choices}(1)
        \choice US System of Units
        \choice EU System of Units
        \choice Imperial System
        \choice\correct The Metric System
    \end{choices}
\end{exercise}
```

Comment: Yes, refstepping is now needed, cf. https://github.com/cgnieder/tasks/issues/23 and https://github.com/cgnieder/tasks/issues/24

Comment: THANK YOU so much!!! Adding the refstepcounter worked!